# Get separate JSON from the response

Tags: android, json, node.js, http

My team & I are working on a chatting app: an Android client, & a web client.
Recently, we stumbled up a blocking issue. Here is how:

So the web & the Android client (I will refer to them as 'the clients' from now on) communicate with a Node.js server.

We're actually working on the login/signup section. This is an example of what we have so far:

### Android client

- MainActivity.java

  ```
  Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
  loginButton.setOnClickListener(new LoginListener());

  private class LoginListener implements View.OnClickListener {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          CustomAsyncTask manageSession = new CustomAsyncTask();
          Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
          params.put("postURL", "/signin");
          params.put("username", mUsername.getText().toString());
          params.put("password", mPassword.getText().toString());
          manageSession.execute(params);
      }
  }
  ```

Briefly, what this code does, is that it sends a parametrized **POST** request to the **/signin** route.

### Web client

```
<form ...>...</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.post('/signin',{username : $('#username').val(),password :$('#password').val()});
    })
</script>
```

### Server side

```
// signin post
app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM User WHERE ((username = "' + req.body.username + '" OR email = "' + req.body.username + '") AND password = "' + req.body.password + '")', function (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // If the user entered a valid username or email, then check for the password
        if (rows.length > 0 && rows[0].password == rows[0].password) {
            res.render('index', { status: "SUCCESS", username: req.body.username })
        } else {
            // Valid username or email, but invalid password
            res.render('index', { status: "FAILURE", username: req.body.username })
        }
    });
})
```

### The problem

As you can see from the code snippets above, the clients send **POST** requests to the `/signin` route, but:

- The Android client expects **pure JSON** as a response
- The web client expects a **whole page** as a response ***(index.ejs)***

`res.render()` solves the problem for **client 2**, `res.end({json})` solves it for **client 1**.

*Is there a way we could separate the response, so that each client gets what it wants ?

 What is the optimal way to work this out ?*

Comment: Send another parameter as boolean named it `isWeb` and send the value as true and false depending on which client you are using. and now you can make two separate responses, Isn't it?

Comment: Another way is to send the device type like android, ios , web etc, according to the device type you can give response

Comment: Hm, you could set an accept header parameter. Like "accept: application/json". Access them server-side via res.headers so you can determine what to send back.

Comment: @Clairvoyant any side effects I should know about ?

Comment: @JörnBuitink sounds doeable.

Comment: Hmm don't know if there is any side effect.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, the **extra parameter** & the **header parameter** tricks would definitely help us out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra variable to get if it is coming from web or android and then do as needed.
e.g.-

```
app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM User WHERE ((username = "' + req.body.username + '" OR email = "' + req.body.username + '") AND password = "' + req.body.password + '")', function (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // If the user entered a valid username or email, then check for the password
        if (rows.length > 0 && rows[0].password == rows[0].password) {
            if(req.body.device_type == "web"){
                res.render('index', { status: "SUCCESS", username: req.body.username })
            }
            else{
                res.end({ status: "SUCCESS", username: req.body.username })
            }
        } else {
            // Valid username or email, but invalid password
            if(req.body.device_type == "web"){
                res.render('index', { status: "FAILURE", username: req.body.username })
            }
            else{
                res.end({ status: "FAILURE", username: req.body.username })
            }
        }
    });
})
```

and in android:-

```
params.put("postURL", "/signin");
params.put("username", mUsername.getText().toString());
params.put("password", mPassword.getText().toString());
params.put("device_type", "android");
manageSession.execute(params);
```

in web:-

```
$.post('/signin',{username : $('#username').val(),password :$('#password').val(),device_type:'web'});
```

Let me know if there's any more problem.

Comment: If this works for you then please accept the answer @Sparta